Remix run redirect function changes url but not the UI
The behaviour is that on fetcher.submit url changes but the UI/view stays the same.
Here is the code:
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const { data } = getSearchParams(
    request,
    zod.object({ redirect: zod.boolean() }),
  );
  if (data?.redirect) return redirect("/home");

  return null;
};

I've also tried with navigate('/home')

I created a StackBlitz showing how to use redirect
// app/routes/login.tsx
export async function action({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const username = formData.get('username');
  if (!username) {
    return json({ error: true, message: 'require username and password' });
  }
  let url = new URL(request.url);
  let returnUrl = url.searchParams.get('returnUrl') ?? '/home';
  return redirect(returnUrl, {
    headers: {
      'set-cookie': await userCookie.serialize({ username }),
    },
  });
}

// app/routes/logout.tsx
export async function action() {
  return redirect('/', {
    headers: {
      'set-cookie': 'user=; Max-Age=0', // expire cookie
    },
  });
}

// app/user.server.ts
export async function requireUser(request: Request) {
  let user = await getUser(request);
  if (!user) {
    let url = new URL(request.url);
    throw redirect(`/login?returnUrl=${url.pathname}${url.search}`);
  }
  return user;
}

⚡️ StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-muhac1
